# Cutting movie with ffmpeg result in audio/video desync

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I've concate long ago set of movies taken during some lecture. Now I want to cut them for each question/answer.

I do it like this.

> ffmpeg -ss 00:00:34.7 -t 00:10:44.6 -y -i input_movie.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output_1.mp4
>
> ffmpeg -ss 00:11:22.2 -y -i input_movie.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output_2.mp4

Yet, for the second part I can't set proper starting point so audio and video would be in sync. 
Usually I could fix it with small tweeks in cut start time (like .1, .2, and so on). For this case this doesn't work. 
When I play second cut in mplayer video is few second behind audio (where audio is cut properly). When I jump forward and back - all is again in sync.

Where's the problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I cut with RE-ENCODING - problem is gone.

> ffmpeg -ss 00:00:34.7 -t 00:10:44.6 -y -i input_movie.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 128koutput_1.mp4